# Neural Network Input Arrangement and Normalization Dependencies

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Not sure if this is one or two questions, and while I think that the answer to both questions is "no, it will not make a difference", you and I have both been wildly wrong to other silly questions before.

1. Are neural network inputs dependent on their arrangement with one another?  For example, if I have 7 neurons representing the days of the week, instead of arranging them in the common-sense manner of SMTWRFS, could I arrange them as MFRSSTW if done consistently in my training, validation and testing sets?  Or would this somehow affect the machine's ability to learn patterns based on our (humans, society, etc.) typical arrangement of the days of the week?  THIS IS ONLY AN EXMAPLE!  But it demonstrates an extreme example of my question.  Obviously, ths is more difficult for humans to follow, so I would not be doing this unless it made sense from a data collection standpoint or due to some other restriction.

*I belive the answer to this question is NO, since all of the neurons are fully interconnected and the synapse weights adjusted to accomodate the emergent patterns, regardless of their position with respect to one another.

2a. Is input normalization dependent on each other, or can they be normalized seperately as long as it is done consistently?  For example, inputs 1-8 normalized from (0, 200) -> (-1, 1), and inputs 8-10 normaled from (0, 100000) -> (-1, 1), and then used altogether for the learning/computation.

2a. Can the output be *denormalized* independent of the inputs?  Same example as above, inputs 1-8 normalized from (0, 200) -> (-1, 1), and inputs 8-10 normaled from (0, 100000) -> (-1, 1), but the ouputs normalized from (-1, 1) -> (0, 5000)?

*I would think that as long as the normalization and denormalizations are done consistently when being presented to the network, this should not make a difference in either scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you suspect, the inputs of an artificial neural network (at least in the widely used multilayer perceptron) can be arranged arbitrarily. The prediction/classification results are independent of the arrangement of the inputs.
2. The goal of the normalization stage is that the mean of all the variables should be close to zero, and their variances should be similar, typically close to 1. Therefore, as you point, each variable must be normalized independently. A similar case happens with the outputs.

Normalization is not required from a theoretical point of view, however, is an important step in the practical application of the artificial neural networks. This and other practical tricks about neural networks can be found in [LeCun's paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf).